# where is Sql Agent Job in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have downloaded Sql Server 2008 from  this link

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=25174

but I m unable to see Sql Agent Job in Sql Server 2008

[image]

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't there because SQL Agent is NOT part of the free Express edition. [Take a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.ASPX) to see what is and isn't included in the Express edition.

Answer (score 4):

Note that SQL Server Agent is a feature only in the Enterprise, Standard, Web, Workgroup, and Datacenter editions.

However, in some situations you can use Windows scheduler to execute a task via a batch file.